# Why is the answer for this problem 8 sq. units?

Tags: geometry, contest-math

If a unit sphere $(r = 1)$ circumscribes a cube, what is the surface area of the said cube?

The answer for this problem is 8 sq. units. However, my solution is as follows:

Diameter of sphere = Diagonal of Cube (through observation of cross section)
This means that through Pythagorean theorem:
$$\begin{align}2s^2= (\sqrt{2})^2 = 2 \\ s^2 = 2\\ 6s^2 = 12 \end{align}$$

What is wrong with this solution? Am I missing something here?

Comment: The first thing wrong with your "solution" is that you introduce the symbol $s$ without telling anyone what it stands for.

Comment: The second thing wrong is that from $2s^2=2$ you shouldn't get $s^2=2$.

Answer (score 9):

The body diagonal of a cube is actually $s\sqrt{3}$. The face diagonals are $s\sqrt{2}$.

There is a right angled triangle formed by a vertical side $s$, the bottom face diagonal $s\sqrt{2}$ and the body diagonal. You use pythagoras theorem on that triangle to get the above

Comment: i still do not follow. can you please tell me how we are able to get 8 from this? Does this mean that the body diagonal is the one that is 2 units long and not the face diagonal?

Comment: @AzzLikar The diagonal of the cube is the diameter of the sphere or $2$.  Pythagoras gives $s^2+2s^2=4\implies6s^2=8$

Comment: @AzzLikar : Of course it is the body diagonal that is length $2$.  The body diagonal is the greatest distance between any two points of the cube, so the diameter of a circumscribing sphere has to be at least as long as the body diagonal.

Comment: @EricTowers i understand. thank you